# Differ between two or more click events called from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var option,
Switch (option)
{
   case "A":
   document.getElementById("cell").click();
   break;

   case "B":
    document.getElementById("cell").click();
    break;
   
   default:
   break;
},

clickEventHandlerForCell(event){

//When case A
alert("I am fired from case A");

// When case B
alert("I am fired from case B");

}
```

A button is clicked from JavaScript code. How to send a value to the handler function to tell, from where it was called? I read that there is a method to tell the difference between the real click and fake click, but I couldn't find a question differing two fake links.'Pure' JavaScript is preferable.

Comment: you can just use addEventListener()

Comment: Do you need to go via a click handler, or could you abstract that into a separate function that takes an argument?  The click handler could then call it with a default value, and your `switch` statement can call it directly, specifying whether it's `A` or `B`

Comment: first your code is invalid, second `console.log(event);` and see what it contains.

Comment: @epascarello I just wanted to provide a pseudo-code to get the idea of functionality. Thank for pointing out the event object. Is it possible to set some variable in the event object before calling the click() function?

Comment: There should be no need to set a variable, the object that was clicked should be there.

Comment: But I am clicking the same button from 2 different places. What could be inside event object that could tell me the difference between two event objects?

Comment: I thought you were clicking on different elements, not the same element from a different place. Weird design. Set a data attribute on the element.

Comment: @vikas-bansal Provide HTML will very helpfull to understand your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I thought you meant**

The event object holds what was clicked. So you can handle the data that way.

```js
function clicked(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-item"));
}





document.getElementById("tab").addEventListener("click", clicked);

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
tds[0].click();
tds[1].click();
```

```html
<table id="tab">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-item="1">1</td>
      <td data-item="2">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**What you actually wanted**

```js
    function clicked(event) {
      console.log(event.target.getAttribute("data-action"));
      event.target.removeAttribute("data-action");
    }

    document.getElementById("tab").addEventListener("click", clicked);

    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

    tds[0].setAttribute("data-action", "A");
    tds[0].click();

    tds[0].setAttribute("data-action", "B");
    tds[0].click();
```

```html
<table id="tab">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```